# Definite integral of exponential function

Tags: calculus, integration, exponential-function

I'd like to get some feedback on an integral calculation, if anyone might spot something wrong with my work:

$$\int_4^9{\frac{2e^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}}\,\,dx$$

Using substitution, let

$$u = \sqrt{x},\,\,\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}},\,\,du=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}dx$$

Working out the indefinite integral

$$\int{\frac{2e^{\sqrt{x}}}{\sqrt{x}}}\,\,dx = 4\int{e^u}\,du = 4\cdot e^u+c = 4 \cdot e^{\sqrt{x}}+c$$

Calculating the definite integral bounds

$$= 4\cdot e^{\sqrt{9}} - 4\cdot e^{\sqrt{4}} = 4\cdot e^3 - 4\cdot e^2 = 4\cdot e^2(e - 1)$$

I'd appreciate any feedback on this calculation!  Thanks.

Comment: This looks *perfect* to me !

Comment: Thank you, Claude.  I appreciate the feedback :)

Comment: It looks just fine. +1

Comment: The calculation is completely right. Just a tiny error, you forgot the $dx$ in the first and second integrals.

Comment: My oversight, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps easier, "identifying" derivatives of functions:

$$\int_4^9\frac{2e^{\sqrt x}}{\sqrt x}dx=4\int_4^9e^{\sqrt x}\;(\sqrt x)' dx=\left.4e^{\sqrt x}\right|_4^9=4(e^3-e^2)$$